# Magento 2.4 - How to enable ajax for add-to-cart button and wishlist button of product widgets on homepage?

Tags: addtocart, ajax, wishlist, magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I have added products on the homepage using the widget, how to enable ajax for add-to-cart button and wishlist button of product widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable AJAX add to cart on home page, You need to add small JS code

create:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="myaddto" template="Magento_Theme::myaddto.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
      </body>
  </page>
```

create:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/myaddto.phtml

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=tocart-form]": {
        "catalogAddToCart": {}
    }
}
</script>
```

Note: If you have any other custom phtml on home page, you can add above in that file as well!

Comment: How to update the "Add to Cart" text to "Show Now"?

Comment: Based on template, you can update text.for example for new products `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml`. OR just enable template path hind for phtml

Comment: Path: app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_PageBuilder\templates\catalog\product\widget\content\carousel.phtml

Code: Line Number : 11 https://codeshare.io/G7wJob

Comment: After the update text is showing "Shop Now", After clicking the show now button again its changed to Add to Cart text, how to update my text permanently?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override addtocart.phtml file

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

Now Just Replace **"bindSubmit": false** to **"bindSubmit": true**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**To**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now delete cache and page_cache folder or flush cache.

**Note: Make sure you have to set No from** `Store->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Shopping Cart->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart to No`

Comment: Path : app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

Code: https://codeshare.io/5zZlMW

Not working, if i click add-to-cart page loading.